# What is the expected value of points earned in a dice game with 5 rolls?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, expected-value, dice

I am playing a dice (6-face) game where I roll 5 times and for each $i$th roll, $i = 1, 2, ..., 5$, I get $1$ point if the number I rolled is strictly larger than $i$. How do I find the expected value of the total points I earned from this game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be a random variable for the number of points earned from the $i$th roll. By linearity of expectation, the expected total points earned is $$\sum_{i=1}^5 \mathbb{E}[X_i].$$

It remains to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$, the expected number of points earned from the $i$th roll, which I will leave to you.